# SQL accumulates previous days results while getting number of records in past 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I've written this SQL query which returns the number of records created per hour in last 24 hours. The query works fine for the first day, But from the second day, it adds the number of records on the first day with the current day count.

Here's my current query:

```
 select h.hr, count(e.eventID) as cnt
from (
    select 0 hr union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all select 15 union all select 16 union all select 17 union all select 18 union all select 19 union all select 20 union all select 21 union all select 22 union all select 23
) h
left join events e 
    on e.timeStamp > now() - interval 24 hour
        and hour(e.timeStamp) = h.hr
group by h.hr
```

My DataSet:

```
+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| eventID | personID | timeStamp           | dateModified        |
+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       1 |        8 | 2019-12-28 12:26:49 | 2019-12-28 12:26:50 |
|       2 |        0 | 2019-12-28 12:26:51 | 2019-12-28 12:26:52 |
|       3 |        0 | 2019-12-28 12:27:11 | 2019-12-28 12:27:12 |
|       4 |        0 | 2019-12-28 12:27:12 | 2019-12-28 12:27:12 |
|       5 |        0 | 2019-12-28 12:28:20 | 2019-12-28 12:28:20 |
|       6 |        0 | 2019-12-28 12:28:21 | 2019-12-28 12:28:21 |
|       7 |        0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2019-12-28 12:28:21 |
|       8 |        2 | 2019-12-28 12:30:02 | 2019-12-28 12:30:02 |
|       9 |        0 | 2019-12-28 12:30:03 | 2019-12-28 12:30:03 |
|      10 |        1 | 2019-12-30 05:38:02 | 2019-12-30 05:38:01 |
|      11 |        0 | 2019-12-30 05:38:05 | 2019-12-30 05:38:03 |
|      12 |        0 | 2019-12-30 05:41:42 | 2019-12-30 05:41:41 |
|      13 |        1 | 2019-12-30 05:41:41 | 2019-12-30 05:41:41 |
|      14 |        1 | 2019-12-30 05:43:11 | 2019-12-30 05:43:11 |
|      15 |        0 | 2019-12-30 05:43:13 | 2019-12-30 05:43:11 |
|      16 |        8 | 2019-12-30 05:44:08 | 2019-12-30 05:44:08 |
|      17 |        0 | 2019-12-30 05:44:10 | 2019-12-30 05:44:08 |
|      18 |        1 | 2019-12-30 05:48:06 | 2019-12-30 05:48:06 |
|      19 |        0 | 2019-12-30 05:48:08 | 2019-12-30 05:48:07 |
|      20 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:09:58 | 2019-12-30 06:09:57 |
|      21 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:10:00 | 2019-12-30 06:09:58 |
|      22 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:11:22 | 2019-12-30 06:11:20 |
|      23 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:11:20 | 2019-12-30 06:11:20 |
|      24 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:13:30 | 2019-12-30 06:13:30 |
|      25 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:13:32 | 2019-12-30 06:13:30 |
|      26 |        0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2019-12-30 06:13:42 |
|      27 |        0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2019-12-30 06:14:00 |
|      28 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:14:55 | 2019-12-30 06:14:54 |
|      29 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:14:57 | 2019-12-30 06:14:55 |
|      30 |        0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2019-12-30 06:14:59 |
|      31 |        8 | 2019-12-30 06:16:22 | 2019-12-30 06:16:22 |
|      32 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:16:24 | 2019-12-30 06:16:22 |
|      33 |        0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2019-12-30 06:16:27 |
|      34 |        8 | 2019-12-30 06:17:56 | 2019-12-30 06:17:56 |
|      35 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:17:58 | 2019-12-30 06:17:56 |
|      36 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:18:32 | 2019-12-30 06:18:31 |
|      37 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:18:33 | 2019-12-30 06:18:31 |
|      38 |        0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2019-12-30 06:18:37 |
|      39 |        8 | 2019-12-30 06:21:23 | 2019-12-30 06:21:23 |
|      40 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:21:25 | 2019-12-30 06:21:23 |
|      41 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:21:33 | 2019-12-30 06:21:32 |
|      42 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:21:34 | 2019-12-30 06:21:32 |
|      43 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:39:58 | 2019-12-30 06:39:57 |
|      44 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:40:00 | 2019-12-30 06:39:59 |
|      45 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:40:29 | 2019-12-30 06:40:29 |
|      46 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:40:31 | 2019-12-30 06:40:29 |
|      47 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:42:06 | 2019-12-30 06:42:05 |
|      48 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:42:07 | 2019-12-30 06:42:05 |
|      49 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:44:21 | 2019-12-30 06:44:20 |
|      50 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:44:22 | 2019-12-30 06:44:21 |
|      51 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:45:35 | 2019-12-30 06:45:34 |
|      52 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:45:36 | 2019-12-30 06:45:34 |
|      53 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:46:27 | 2019-12-30 06:46:27 |
|      54 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:46:28 | 2019-12-30 06:46:27 |
|      55 |        1 | 2019-12-30 06:50:40 | 2019-12-30 06:50:39 |
|      56 |        0 | 2019-12-30 06:50:41 | 2019-12-30 06:50:39 |
|      57 |        8 | 2019-12-30 08:10:52 | 2019-12-30 08:10:57 |
|      58 |        0 | 2019-12-30 08:10:59 | 2019-12-30 08:10:58 |
|      59 |        1 | 2019-12-30 09:47:06 | 2019-12-30 09:47:07 |
|      60 |        0 | 2019-12-30 09:47:08 | 2019-12-30 09:47:07 |
|      61 |        1 | 2019-12-30 11:43:17 | 2019-12-30 11:43:17 |
|      62 |        0 | 2019-12-30 11:43:18 | 2019-12-30 11:43:18 |
|      63 |        1 | 2019-12-30 11:43:35 | 2019-12-30 11:43:35 |
|      64 |        0 | 2019-12-30 11:43:36 | 2019-12-30 11:43:35 |
|      65 |        1 | 2019-12-30 11:44:05 | 2019-12-30 11:44:05 |
|      66 |        0 | 2019-12-30 11:44:06 | 2019-12-30 11:44:06 |
|      67 |        1 | 2019-12-30 12:26:47 | 2019-12-30 12:26:47 |
|      68 |        0 | 2019-12-30 12:26:49 | 2019-12-30 12:26:48 |
|      69 |        0 | 2019-12-30 12:40:34 | 2019-12-30 12:40:33 |
|      70 |        1 | 2019-12-30 12:40:33 | 2019-12-30 12:40:34 |
|      71 |        8 | 2019-12-31 04:52:29 | 2019-12-31 04:52:28 |
|      72 |        0 | 2019-12-31 04:52:31 | 2019-12-31 04:52:29 |
|      73 |        0 | 2019-12-31 04:53:50 | 2019-12-31 04:53:47 |
|      74 |        8 | 2019-12-31 04:53:48 | 2019-12-31 04:53:47 |
|      75 |        8 | 2019-12-31 04:54:14 | 2019-12-31 04:54:13 |
|      76 |        0 | 2019-12-31 04:54:16 | 2019-12-31 04:54:14 |
|      77 |        8 | 2019-12-31 04:54:40 | 2019-12-31 04:54:38 |
|      78 |        0 | 2019-12-31 04:54:41 | 2019-12-31 04:54:39 |
|      79 |        0 | 2019-12-31 04:55:11 | 2019-12-31 04:55:09 |
|      80 |        8 | 2019-12-31 04:55:10 | 2019-12-31 04:55:10 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Where am I going wrong?

This is my timeStamp format incase someone needs it: `2019-12-31 04:55:10`

P.S: My sql does not support recursive CTEs so I had to use union 24 times.

Comment: Shrihari, can you post sample of the data in the table events please so we can run the test on our side?

Comment: Sure. Give me a minute.

Comment: @zip I've added my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have the test data but this cold be what you need:

```
 select h.hr, count(e.eventID) as cnt
from (
    select 0 hr union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all select 15 union all select 16 union all select 17 union all select 18 union all select 19 union all select 20 union all select 21 union all select 22 union all select 23
) h
left join (select * from events e where e.timeStamp > now() - interval 24 hour) e
        on hour(e.timeStamp) = h.hr
group by h.hr
```

IF

```
select * from events e where e.timeStamp > now() - interval 24 hour
```

gives you just the records of the last 24 hours

**IF you want events of the last day:**

```
select h.hr, count(e.eventID) as cnt
from (
    select 0 hr union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all select 15 union all select 16 union all select 17 union all select 18 union all select 19 union all select 20 union all select 21 union all select 22 union all select 23
) h
left join (select * from events e where e.timeStamp > cast(now()  as date)) e
        on hour(e.timeStamp) = h.hr
group by h.hr
```

Comment: Still the same result unfortunately :(

Comment: Hi Shrihari, I run the test in sqlfiddle and select * from events e where e.timeStamp > now() - interval 24 hour gives 56 events. If I run the query in my reply, I get those 56 events, which are within the last 24 hours. See in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a8fbc/3 . Isn't it the expected result? If not what should we get?

Comment: I'm counting the number of records in each hour of past 24 hours, My current query gives ```0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 28, 0, 2, 2, 0, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,``` Which is definitely the data with previous two days added. I'm currently on the 4th hour of the day. But how can the rest of the places be filled?

Comment: the first query fill the hours past the fourth because it computes on a sliding 24 hours window. So the hours you see after the fourth are from the previous day. However if you just want the events of the current day, its added at the end of my answer

Comment: Use `CURDATE()` for midnight of this morning.